# I need to pass a variabe from a property file in java as a string

Tags: java, string, properties

I have a property file from which I am reading content.

In my application I have a variable declared as `String foo="abc";` and in my `.property file`  I have a String `message=this is a message for '"+foo+"'` which have a get  method `String _message = property.getProperty("message");`.

The `system.out.println(_message);` is displaying this is a message for `"+foo+"'` but I want to display this is a message for `abc`

How can I achieve this,
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could store your message as a `String` format in your properties file.

**For example:**

```
message=this is a message for '%s'
```

Then use [`String#format(String format, Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to get the corresponding message

```
String myMessage = String.format(property.getProperty("message"), foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) or [`MessageFormat.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). You'll have to slightly change the value of the property value, but you'll also have much bigger flexibility, like formatting values as numbers, or dates, with a pattern, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No.
getProperty() won't evaluate message as if it was code.
Do something like

```
message=this is a message for $1
```

then

```
String _message = property.getProperty("message").replace("$1",foo);
```